# Windows Defender scans more files than there are on my drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender

I'm trying to run a Windows Defender full scan, but it seems to be scanning more files than are on my PC (32M files) and the progress bar doesn't move, even though the number of files scanned increases. Also, it's been running much longer than usual.

[image: Windows Defender]

Here is a screenshot from WinDirStat, which shows I have only ~2M files on my drive.

[image: WinDirStat]

What can be a reason for this? If it's caused by a corrupted file/directory how can I find out which one it is?

Comment: Try repairing Windows Defender. Open the WD app (system tray). Click 'Virus and security protection'. 
Check for updates and install the latest version.  Restart and test Defender

Comment: If some file is archived one (ZIP, MSI, etc.) then Defender unpacks it (if possible) and checks all inner files counting them separately. So total amout of scanned files is above the amount of files on the drive.

Comment: @Akina I have some zipped files, but it's definitely less than 30M.

Comment: @John did this, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try the initial OS repairs.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: *I have some zipped files, but it's definitely less than 30M.* Open Explorer. Find some MSI file. Click it with right mouse button and select "Scan with Defender". See in the report window how many files were checked during this one file scanning.

Comment: exe files also have many files compressed inside the exe.